# C# create list of generic items to pass to function that takes base class

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

I have a function that takes a base class as a parameter:

```
public List<Items> MyFunction(List<List<IBaseItemClass>> myList){}
```

I then want to create a list to pass to this function.  The list will be made up of objects derived from classes that implement `IBaseItemClass`.

```
List<List<IBaseItemClass>> myList = new List<List<IBaseItemClass>>();
```

I already have some objects that are derived from a class that implements `IBaseItemClass` and returns a list of derived items.

```
List<DerivedItem1> derivedItem1 = service.GetItem<DerivedItem1>(param1);
List<DerivedItem2> derivedItem2 = service.GetItem<DerivedItem2>(param1);
```

How can I assign `derivedItem1` and `derivedItem1` to `myList`?

This does not work: `myList.Add(derivedItemList);`

My objective is to pass in a list of lists that hold objects that implement `IBaseItemClass` to `MyFunction` so that I can process them all in the same manner since they implement the same base class.

Comment: `myList` clearly takes *lists* of `IBaseItemClass`, so you can't add single items, you have to add lists of them.

Comment: Not an ideal solution but a work around, try adding like this: myList.Add(derivedItemList.Select(item => item as IBaseItemClass).ToList());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since DerivedItem1 inherits from IBaseItemClass but myList.Add() expects List of IBaseItemClass.

And you are giving it a List of DerivedItem1 that doesn't inherits from List of IBaseItemClass anyways.

Here is a solution, not an ideal one but a workaround, try adding like this, it should work:

```
myList.Add(derivedItemList.Select(item => item as IBaseItemClass).ToList());
```

Or simply use the IEnumerable extension method Cast as suggested by @juharr in the comments as:

```
myList.Add(derivedItemList.Cast<IBaseItemClass>().ToList());
```

Comment: Thank you Rashid.  Could you please explain why your suggestion works and why it is not ideal.  How would you suggest accomplishing what I'm trying to accomplish in a better way.

Comment: Rashid, one other thing I had tried along the lines of your suggestion was: `myList.Add(derivedItem1 as List<IBaseItemClass>);`  But that did not work either.

Comment: You can pass a derived class object to a function that expects the base class object as parameter but List<IBaseItemClass> and IBaseItemClass are two different types. and DerivedItem1 is derived from IBaseItemClass but List<DerivedItem1> is not derived from List<IBaseItemClass>, so you would have to convert each item of the list being passed to the base class to make it acceptable.

Comment: It's simpler to just use `Cast<IBaseItemClass>()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

myList is a List of List of objects. But you tried to pass in a single object to myList.Add(). That’s why it is failing.
You’ll need to create the individual List objects first and then add them to myList.

Comment: I've made edits to clarify that `derivedItem` is a list.  I've changed the name to `derivedItemList`.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the lists as `List<IBaseItemClass>` instead of `List<DerivedItem>`. Such list has no problem holding instances of DerivedItem And it Will satisfy the list of lists.